# Amazon EC2 - Prompted for Password when Switching to Passwordless User

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04

## Some background ...

I've just started using Amazon EC2 and I have a question regarding users and passwords.

As you surely well know, the default user (which in the case of Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS is named `ubuntu`) doesn't have a password but instead uses public-private key authentication to login.

For reference, here's the contents of my `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloudimg-ubuntu` file:

`# ubuntu user is default user in cloud-images.
# It needs passwordless sudo functionality.
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

## My question ...

I've since created a second user named `jdoe` who is a member of the `admin` group. The user `jdoe` has a password as well as a public-private key pair.

When logged in as `jdoe` I try to switch to the default `ubuntu` user using the following command, but I'm unexpectedly prompted for a password. How come? The user `ubuntu` (afaik) doesn't have a password!

`jdoe@host:~$ su ubuntu
Password:`

Thanks in advance for your help and comments!

Comment: I should add that I've had success using the command `sudo su ubuntu`. But this looks rather ugly, and I was in doubt whether this was the *right thing* to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`su` and `sudo` are 2 different things and you're getting confused.

When you login as `ubuntu` and run any command using `sudo`, it will not ask for password because of `ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

Now `jdoe` is a part of `admin` group but `admin` groups needs to provide password as per `%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL`. This statement is found by running `visudo`. Please note that this statement does not have `NOPASSWD:ALL`

So when user `jdoe` runs any command as `sudo`, he has to enter the password

Now, `su` is entirely different aspect than`sudo`. And when you run `su ubuntu`, there is no `sudo` thing in picture. So it will ask you for the password of user `ubuntu`.

In otehrwords, the statement `jdoe@host:~$ su ubuntu` is asking you to enter the password of user `ubuntu`. As you do not have password for `ubuntu` set, this will never succeed.

However, if you login as `ubuntu` and try `sudo su jdoe`, it will not ask for any a pssword. But.... if you login as `ubuntu` and run `su jdoe`, it will ask you for the password of user `jdoe`. Try this so you get better understanding around how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However, the question still stands: What is the *right* way to switch to a different user within my existing shell session? Is it indeed `jdoe@host:~$ sudo su ubuntu`?

Comment: with `sudo` you don't have to share the password across different users and need to control the access using `sudoers`. With `su`, you have to share the password. So doing `sudo su <username>` is perfectly fine.